# Matrix columns zeroing, C language

Tags: c, matrix

I need to make a little project but I completely don't know how. Im giving matrix A of size n, and it have to return me matrix B which is matrix A with zeroed first and penultimate column. All I did is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
int i,n,j,;
int tab[n][n];
printf("Size of matrix:");
scanf("%d",&n);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    printf("A[%d][%d]=",i,j);
    scanf("%lf",&tab[i][j]);
}
printf("Data:");
printf("Matrix A[%d][%d]",n,m);
}
```

Which I think should let me to type my matrix. What I should do next? Please help me.

Comment: Hint: With `int i,n,j,;
int tab[n][n];`, what is the value of `n` as used in `int tab[n][n];`?

Comment: Best to post true compilable code: `printf("Matrix A[%d][%d]",n,m);`  Where is `m` defined?

Comment: note that `int[n]` is non standard c. To be standard, if you want a dynamically sized array, you need to use malloc, free etc

Comment: @pm100 Variable Length Arrays is absolutely standard C.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya yup - its c++ that hates them

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of errors in your code, the variable m is not declared, the double array is declared with n non-initialized. As the size of matrix is only known at runtime (entered by user), you need to use dynamic memory allocation functions to allocate memory for your matrix.

Try this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, j, n;
    printf("Size of matrix: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int *tab = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n*n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
         for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
         {
             printf("A[%d][%d]=",i,j);
             scanf("%d",(tab+i*n+j));
         }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        *(tab+i*n) = 0;
        *(tab+i*n+n-2) = 0;
    }

    //Print tab
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
             printf("%d ", *(tab+i*n+j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```